# Draw vertical nodes in org chart by javascript

Tags: javascript, orgchart

I want to draw an organizational chart with vertical nodes, using html and javascript [like those ones in this picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LQfsK.png).

In my code i am importing data from google sheet and drawing an horizontal org chart but the problem that is with the long data i will have the chart will become more larger.

```html
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>
  <div id="orgchart_admin"></div>
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.gstatic.com/charts/loader.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript">
    google.charts.load('current', {'packages' : ['orgchart', 'table']});
    google.charts.setOnLoadCallback(function() { initialize('') });

    function initialize() {
      document.getElementById('orgchart_admin').innerHTML = "<i class='fa fa-spinner fa-spin fa-3x fa-fw'></i>";
      
      var dataSourceUrl = 'https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/6dPVwx_LNfpo0ArgiJOYteBmZNR7cWsjDhYIZKc20pY/gviz/tq?';

      // Tells it that the first row contains headers: 'Role', 'Reports To', 'Name'
      var query = new google.visualization.Query(dataSourceUrl + '&headers=1');

      // Send the query with a callback function.
      query.send(handleQueryResponse);
    }

    function handleQueryResponse(response) {
      // Called when the query response is returned.
      if (response.isError()) {
        alert('Error in query: ' + response.getMessage() + ' ' + response.getDetailedMessage());
        return;
      }

      var raw_data = response.getDataTable();
      var data = new google.visualization.DataTable();

      data.addColumn('string', 'Entity');
      data.addColumn('string', 'ParentEntity');
      data.addColumn('string', 'ToolTip');

      // Loops through all rows and populates a new DataTable with formatted values for the orgchart
      var num_rows = raw_data.getNumberOfRows();
      for (var i = 0; i < num_rows; i++) {
        var role = raw_data.getValue(i, 0);
        var reportsTo = raw_data.getValue(i,1);
        var name = raw_data.getValue(i,2) != null ? raw_data.getValue(i,2) : '';

        data.addRows([[
          { v: role,
            f: "<a class='role' href='#'>" + name + "<br/>" + role + "</a>"
          }, 
          reportsTo, 
          name]]);
      }

      // Loops through all rows and populates a new DataTable with formatted values for the orgchart
      var container = document.getElementById('orgchart_admin');
      var chart = new google.visualization.OrgChart(container);
      chart.draw(data, {allowHtml:true, 'size': 'large'});
    }      
  </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Thank you
All the help is welcome.

Comment: What do you want to achieve? What have you tried so far (include code)?

Comment: StackOverflow is for help with existing code and code problems. Your question(?) falls outside of this scope. Please clarify what you have already tried and what you need help with.

Comment: @EmilS.Jørgensen done, i modified my post

Comment: @SoukainaBoukir I can't seem to run your snippet. You have probably already read this, but here is Googles tutorial on [Google Chart Org-chart](https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/gallery/orgchart). You say your problem is that the Chart gets too large?

Comment: @EmilS.Jørgensen yes indeed, when a have a important number of nodes, it's getting larging and displaying a scroll, that's why i m looking for a way to show them vertically

Comment: you can use BALKANGraph library with mixed layout: https://balkangraph.com/OrgChartJS/Docs/Layout

Answer (score 0):

Google orgchart does not support mixed layout. You can use [OrgChart JS](https://balkangraph.com) to achieve requested functionality. Here is an example:

```js
 var chart = new OrgChart(document.getElementById("tree"), {    
            layout: BALKANGraph.mixed,
            nodeBinding:{
              field_0: "id"
            },
            enableSearch: false,
            nodes: [
                { id: "1"  },
                { id: "2", pid: "1"},
                { id: "3", pid: "1"},
                { id: "4", pid: "2"},
                { id: "5", pid: "2"},
                { id: "6", pid: "3"},
                { id: "7", pid: "3"}
            ]
        });
```

```css
        html, body {
            margin: 0px;
            padding: 0px;
            width: 100%;
            height: 100%;
            overflow: hidden;
            text-align: center;
            font-family: "Trebuchet MS";
        }

        #tree {
            width: 100%;
            height: 100%;
            position: relative;
        }
```

```html
<script src="https://balkangraph.com/js/latest/OrgChart.js"></script>
<div id="tree"/>
```

And the result is almost like those ones on the picture you provided